# Why does JPA Spring Boot place the MySQL data in wrong order?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application with JPA that stores values into a MySQL server. But sometimes it does not insert the data correctly.

I did a ladder graph by doing steps up then steps down. It was not successful as you can see.
[image]

[image]

A sample of the data from MySQL looks like this. Here we can see 2633 at the beginning and then 2633 at the end. In the middle we can see 3096 and 2901. This is not in a correct order.

[image]

The entity of the database looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataLogg {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    // X axis for the plot
    private String dateTime;
    
    // Y Axis for the plot
    private int DO0;
    private int DO1;
    private int DO2;
    private int DO3;
    private float AI0;
    private float AI1;
    private float AI2;
    private float AI3;
    
    // Other
    private long loggerId;
    private int samplingTime;
    private int pulseNumber;
    private int breakPulseLimit;
    private boolean stopSignal;
    private String comment;
}
```

This is how I insert the data:

```
        private DataLoggRepository dataLoggRepository;
        DataLogg dataLogg = new DataLogg(0, time, DO0, DO1, DO2, DO3, AI0, AI1, AI2, AI3, loggerIdValue, samplingTimeValue, pulseNumber, ControlView.selectedBreakPulseLimit, stopSignal, comment);
```

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/c5d50cb7f3b80d4911605859d1d222d3b6a4e9fe/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/components/threads/SamplingThread.java#L167
dataLoggRepository.save(dataLogg);

**Question:**

Is there any way to insert data in correct order and make sure that the data will be inserted at the exactly correct moment?

Comment: How are you querying the data?  Any `order by` clauses?

Comment: @stdunbar I don't know. I don't know what `order by` means. But I'm sure that I have forgot to implement something.

Comment: A database such as MySQL may not order things the way you expect, especially if there are table indexes.  I'm not positive that I fully understand your code but it looks like you want to read the data out with something like `select * from dataLog order by samplingTime` though I'm not positive of your column names in the database.  [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) goes into some basics of retrieving data (the `select` keyword) from a database.

Comment: @stdunbar I have no problem to read the database. But when I insert data, it become some kind of delay with the data. I don't want that delay.

Comment: It sounds like you **think** there is a delay because the data isn't ordered correctly.  If you're not ordering the data when you read it out then you cannot guarantee what it looks like.  If order is important then you *must* have an `order by` to pull it back out.

Comment: @stdunbar But if I try to insert it correctly. Should I use `.saveAndFlush()` method instead of `save()` method?

Comment: **It does not matter how you insert it - it matters how you pull it back out.**  Please take a look at the link I gave and understand database basics.

Comment: @stdunbar The left column is the ID column. It's correct indexed. So I don't know why I should use `order by` in this case.

Comment: @stdunbar The `F` column is not correct inserted as you see. It's a delay.

Comment: @stdunbar you don't understand the question. I want to save data in the same order as I will read it. If I write data slowly, then it will work. If I write data at e.g each 100 ms, then the database will insert data in half-ish random order.

Comment: What I believe @stdunbar is trying to tell you is JPA doesn't guarantee the order of insertion, and neither does the database. And the database most certainly does **not** guarantee any specific order when you just do a bare SQL `SELECT`. If there is a logical ordering on the inserted data, there should be a column in the data itself that reflects that, and you need to sort by that column when selecting the data. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql) for more information

Comment: @crizzis I think I will solve this by using `OrderByDateTime` in the `repository` java class for the `entity` :)